# if check box value is = "something" get value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a quiz. But before starting, the user can select which questions he wants to appear, for that, I have a group of checkboxes, each checkbox has a value, e.g.:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkHA" id="check1" value="1">
                          
    <label for="check1">Heart of Algebra</label>
</li>

<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkGLE" id="check4" value="2">
                          
    <label for="check4">Graphing linear equations</label>
</li>
```

The checkbox value corresponds to the value of the array where the questions are. I want as a checkbox is checked it takes the questions that match its value and display on quiz.

Make sense? if not, can I rephrase the question.

Comment: Please, when asking questions try always to show the minimal effort in resolving your own problem by providing a [mcve] with the best code you tried so far and you're having issues with. Read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use the same `name` attribute  value for all your checkboxes
- IDs are unnecessary if you wrap your INPUT in LABEL
- Use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to *reduce* a NodeList of Elements to
  an array of checked values:

```js
let choices = [];

const ELS_chk = document.querySelectorAll("[name='chk']");

const changeChoices = () => {
  choices = [...ELS_chk].reduce((a, EL) => {
    if (EL.checked) a.push(EL.value);
    return a;
  }, []);
  console.log(choices)
};

ELS_chk.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("change", changeChoices));
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="1">Heart of Algebra</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="2">Graphing linear equations</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="3">Programming</label>
```

*If* you want the values to match a set of predefined questions, make your values a bit more descriptive, and you could use an Object of arrays:

```js
const questions = {
  "algebra"     : [{q:["1","2"], a:0}, {q:["1","2"], a:1}, {q:["1","2","3"], a:0}],
  "glEquations" : [{q:["1","2","3"], a:2}, {q:["1","2"], a:1}, {q:["1","2"], a:0}],
  "programming" : [{q:["1","2"], a:1}, {q:["1","2","3"], a:1}, {q:["1","2"], a:1}],
};

const ELS_chk = document.querySelectorAll("[name='chk']");

const changeChoices = () => {
  const questionsByChioces = [...ELS_chk].reduce((a, EL) => {
    if (EL.checked) a.push(questions[EL.value]);
    return a;
  }, []);
  console.log(questionsByChioces)
};

ELS_chk.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("change", changeChoices));
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="algebra">Heart of Algebra</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="glEquations">Graphing linear equations</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="programming">Programming</label>
```